# Properties of a matrix having only non zero entries in secondary diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Q. A $100 \times 100$ matrix $A=\left(a_{i, j}\right)$ is such that $a_{i, j}=i$ if $i+j=101$ and $a_{i, j}=0$ otherwise. Which of the following statements are true about $A$?

1. $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix over $\mathbb{R}$
2. $A$ is not similar to a diagonal matrix over $\mathbb{C}$
3. One of the eigenvalues of $A$ is 10
4. None of the real eigenvalues of $A$ exceeds 51

I feel that the characteristic polynomial for this matrix
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & & & 1 \\
0 & 0 & & 2 & 0 \\
& & 3& 0& 0 &  \\
...&&&&&\\
100 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

will be $p(x)=\Pi_{i=1}^{50}(x^2-(i\cdot(101-i)))$, But I am not able to establish it by using properties of determinants in $\det(xI-A)=0$.

Comment: Can you find the eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 100&0},\pmatrix{0&2\\ 99&0},\ldots,\pmatrix{0&50\\ 51&0}$?

Comment: How to connect these eigen values (roots of the product of secondary diagonal entries) with the matrix $A$.

Comment: Simultaneously permute the rows and columns of $A$.

Comment: Ok....I got it...Thnks

Comment: Look on the web with keyword "antidiagonal matrix"

Comment: What can you say about $A^2$ ?